# Bootstrap navbar toggler button doesn't work - show up but doesn't open the navbar (Angular)

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, navbar, togglebutton

I have a simple question about the bootstrap navbar toggler. The toggler does appear when the window gets smaller, but when I click it the navbar doesn't appear. Wondering if someone could take a quick look at my code and point out something that might be missing. Relatively new to bootstrap so any help is much appreciated !! (I also followed all the setup instructions on integrating bootstrap so that also shouldn't be an issue here).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  ">
    <a class="navbar-brand">MY NAME HERE</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
        </li> 
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/blogs">Blogs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/blogs">LinkedIn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

```
nav {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 70px !important;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

a {
    background-color: white;

}

div {
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar-brand {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px !important;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.nav-link {
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    color: black;
    font-family: orpheuspro, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue occurs when you don't import jquery with bootstrap. Bootstrap uses jquery for some features like toggle popup ,dropdowns and  modals etc so it is must.
Please Install [Jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) and import it in angular.json file.